# DDD Layers and External Api

Tags: domain-driven-design, axon

Recently I've been trying to make my web application use separated layers.

If I understand the concept correctly I've managed to extract:

1. Domain layer
   This is where my core domain entities, aggregate roots, value objects reside in. I'm forcing myself to have pure domain model, meaning i do not have any service definitions here. The only thing i define here is the repositories, which is actually hidden because axon framework implements that for me automatically.
2. Infrastructure layer
   This is where the axon implements the repository definitions for my aggregates in the domain layer
3. Projection layer
   This is where the event handlers are implemented to project the data for the read model using MongoDB to persist it. It does not know anything other than event model (plain data classes in kotlin)
4. Application layer
   This is where the confusion starts.
5. Controller layer
   This is where I'm implementing the GraphQL/REST controllers, this controller layer is using the command and query model, meaning it has knowledge about the Domain Layer commands as well as the Projection Layer query model.

As I've mentioned the confusion starts with the application layer, let me explain it a bit with simplified example.

Considering I want a domain model to implement Pokemon fighting logic. I need to use PokemonAPI that would provide me data of the Pokemon names stats etc, this would be an external API i would use to get some data.

Let's say that i would have domain implemented like this:
(Keep in mind that I've stretched this implementation so it forces some issues that i have in my own domain)

```
Pokemon {
  id: ID 
}
```

```
PokemonFight {
  id: ID
  pokemon_1: ID
  pokemon_2: ID

  handle(cmd: Create) {
    publish(PokemonFightCreated)
  }

  handle(cmd: ProvidePokemonStats) {
    //providing the stats for the pokemons
    publish(PokemonStatsProvided)
  }

  handle(cmd: Start) {
    //fights only when the both pokemon stats were provided
    publish(PokemonsFought)
  }
```

The flow of data between layers would be like this.

User -> [HTTP] -> Controller -> [CommandGateway] -> (Application | Domain) -> [EventGateway] -> (Application | Domain)

Let's assume that two of pokemons are created and the use case of pokemon fight is basically that when it gets created the stats are provided and then when the stats are provided the fight automatically starts.

This use case logic can be solved by using event processor or even saga.

However as you see in the PokemonFight aggregate, there is [ProvidePokemonStats] command, which basically provides their stats, however my domain do not know how to get such data, this data is provided with the PokemonAPI.

This confuses me a bit because the use case would need to be implemented on both layers, the application (so it provides the stats using the external api) and also in the domain? the domain use case would just use purely domain concepts. But shouldn't i have one place for the use cases?

If i think about it, the only purpose saga/event processor that lives in the application layer is to provide proper data to my domain, so it can continue with it's use cases. So when external API fails, i send command to the domain and then it can decide what to do.

For example i could just put every saga / event processor in the application, so when i decide to change some automation flow i exactly know what module i need to edit and where to find it.

The other confusion is where i have multiple domains, and i want to create use case that uses many of them and connects the data between them, it immediately rings in my brain that this should be application layer that would use domain APIs to control the use case, because I don't think that i should add dependency of different domain in the core one.

TL;DR

1. What layer should be responsible of implementing the automated process between aggregates (can be single but you know what i mean) if the process requires some external API data.
2. What layer should be responsible of implementing the automated process between aggregates that live in different domains / micro services.

Thank you in advance, and I'm also sorry if what I've wrote sounds confusing or it's too much of text, however any answers about layering the DDD applications and proper locations of the components i would highly appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to put it clear. If you use CQRS:

- In the Write Side (commands): The application services are the command handlers. A cmd handler accesses the domain (repositories, aggreagates, etc) in order to implement a use case.

  If the use case needs to access data from another bounded context (microservice), it uses an infraestructure service (via dependency injection). You define the infraestructure service interface in the application service layer, and the implementation in the infra layer. The infra then access the remote microservice via http rest for example. Or integration through events.
- In the Read Side (queries): The application service is the query method (I think you call it projection), which access the database directly. There's no domain here.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 'Application services are the command handlers' clarified few things for me.

Answer (score 1):

I do agree your wording might be a bit vague, but a couple of things do pop up in my mind which might steer you in the right direction.
Mind you, the wording makes it so that I am not 100% sure whether this is what you're looking for. If it isn't, please comment and correct my on the answer I'll provide, so I can update it accordingly.

Now, before your actual question, I'd firstly like to point out the following.
What I am guessing you're mixing is the notion of the Messages and your Domain Model belonging to the same layer. To me personally, the Messages (aka your Commands, Events and Queries) **are** your *public API*. They are the language your application speaks, so should be freely sharable with **any** component and/or service *within* your Bounded Context.

As such, any component in your 'application layer' contained in the same Bounded Context should be allowed to be aware of this public API. The one in charge of the API will be your Domain Model, that's true, but these concepts have to be shared to be able to communicate with one another.

That said, the component which will provide the states to your aggregate can be viewed from two directions I think.

1. It's a component that handles a specific 'Start Pokemon Match' Command. This component has the smarts to know to firstly retrieve the states prior to being able to dispatch a `Create` and `ProvidePokemonStats` command, thus ensuring it'll consistently create a working match with the stats in it by **not** dispatching any of both of the external stats-retrieval API fails.
2. Your angle in the question is to have an Event Handling Component that reacts on the creation of a Match. From here, I'd state a short-lived saga would be in place, as you'd need to deal with the fault scenario of not being able to retrieve the stats. A regular Event Handler is likely to lean to deal with this correctly.

Regardless of the two options you select, this service *will deal* with messages, a.k.a. your public API. As such it's within your application and not a component others will deal with directly, ever.

When it comes to your second question, I feel the some notion still holds. Two distinct applications/microservices only more so suggests your talking about two different Bounded Contexts. Certainly then a Saga would be in place to coordinate the operations between both contexts. Note that between Bounded Contexts, you want to share consciously when it comes to the public API, as you'd ideally not expose everything to the outside world.

Hope this helps you out and if not, like I said, please comment and provide me guidance how to answer your question properly.

Comment: Thank you again Steven, you helped me alot of times with this DDD things. You answer clarified few things for me but as you say, its vague, too much to properly ask a question but i think that atleast from now i will have better separation between external api and domain. Thank you again.

Comment: Much appreciated @PolishCivil, I'm glad to help out. :-)